# markers on google map from array list

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist

I have multiple markers in an XML file which is parsed to an ArrayList. The parsing works, but I can't seem to show the markers on my map. This is the code I'm using to show the markers on the map:

```
InputStream is = null;
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.markers);

ArrayList<Entry> entries = (ArrayList<Entry>) new ParserParsing().parse(is);
for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++);
//int i = 0;
Double latitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(i).lat);
Double longitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(i).lng);
String icon = entries.get(i).icon;
LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(lng)
.title(icon)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName()))));
}
```

Above you can see the line //int = 0; If I don't put this in then I get errors stating that I need to declare the variable i for the lines entries.get(i).lat and .lng?
I am trying to get this project running just for my own benefit and peace of mind
And I am only getting the first marker from the XML list

Comment: Why do you need to have another `i` in there? You have declared one already (int i=0...). What do you have in the entries `ArrayList`? What is your problem with loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a ; (semicolon) at the end of your for loop line - meaning the loop does nothing, replace this with a { and your code might work

Comment: You sir are a genius! I will mark you answer as the one when Im allowed